# How to move custom built firefox/chrome to another system?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, chromium

i followed chormium custom building instructions https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux/build_instructions.md
and build a chrome which is running fine
and i was able to do same with firefox
but the problems i am facing are

1. even after build is complete if i transfer the whole out/dist folder to a new system it will not work at new system so can anyone tell me how i can build a standalone/portable? what parameters i need for that? my target is to build a custom firefox and chrome (with minor changes in their code) on a server and then download the output to my own computer and other computers
2. the output build size is too huge for a browser? firefox is like 10gb and chrome is like 40gb. is there a way to reduce that size to reasonable size of a browser? or atleast to like couple gb's

first problem is the major problem,
i googled around and tried finding solution but i couldnt not find any.
i hope my problem is clear if not i will be available and filling to answer any questions.
help with either firefox/nightly or chromium or both is appreciated

Thanks